# WebDAV - Request "Show files in folder"?

Tags: webdav, http-1.1

I want to download all *.txt files from a WebDAV share.
Is there a request/methode to get a list of files from this folder?

I´m new to WebDAV and at the w3.org WebDAV methode definition I don´t found this information.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The link you pointed at is not the WebDAV specfication, but the HTTP specification. If you want to list the contents of a directory (collection) you must use the PROPFIND method instead, which should return an XML document with all the information.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-9.1

Comment: Thank you SO much for pointing this out!  What a life saver! :-)