# Delete files using WebDav by pattern

Tags: regex, webdav, cadaver

Is it possible to delete files using WebDav by file name pattern?

For example, I want delete all files with prefix hello (`hello_*`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. All you can do is retrieve all names, find the ones you want to delete, and submit a DELETE request for each one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Read this:

1. [WebDAV - Request “Show files in folder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399358/webdav-request-show-files-in-folder)
2. [Getting a List of Folders (WebDAV)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms992615%28v=exchg.65%29)
3. [Deleting Items (WebDAV)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms879334%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx)

JScript supports regular expressions, so **YES**, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks but getting all filenames from folder is not correct solution for me

Comment: @fedor.belov - Get a full list, use regex to remove not maching items and delete the rest by JScript code.