# Get file names and directory list from web directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get all files names and directory list from one web directory through `http://` using C#.

For example:

```
Directory.GetFiles(folder)**
```

is used to get files list from local directory, same as i want to get files list from web directory.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PortalPage/"))
```

Answer (score 4):

*Well*, I don't believe HTTP has a `"directory index"` you can directly use.

You can't pass `url` to `Directory.GetFiles` method, this method takes as a parameter *physical path of url* (if it is accessible of course).

Check out [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method instead.

> The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the
>   corresponding physical directory on the server.
>
> Path
>
> Specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.
>   If Path starts with either a forward (/) or backward slash (), the
>   MapPath method returns a path as if Path were a full, virtual path. If
>   Path doesn't start with a slash, the MapPath method returns a path
>   relative to the directory of the .asp file being processed.

Comment: +1: side note - `MapPath` going to help only if you are interested in enumerating files on your own server... otherwise not possible (and generally there is no "files" behind most of urls). [Sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) may give some insight if supported by particular server...

Answer (score 1):

HTTP in itself does NOT have any function to list the FILE content in a folder. This is impossible, for one thing, as the HTTP specification does not require a URL to be mapped TO a folder. The whole basis of programmable webpages is based on a URL NOT being mapped to a STATIC file.

However. There ARE many extensions to the HTTP protocol. WebDAV IS a protocol for mapping an HTTP URI to a directory in some location. Check out [here for how to query a WebDAV service for the content of a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399358/webdav-request-show-files-in-folder).

However it can't do recursive queries as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Directory.GetFiles` on a URL.

Consider the example:

```
string baseURL = "http://download.example.org/export/dump/";
WebClient client = new WebClient();            
string content = client.DownloadString(baseURL);
```

Then you run a loop inside.