# read textfile with timestamp

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, download

I have a website that creates a txt file and saves it with a timestamp to the webserver directory.

I need a client based app to list all files in the directory to download to the client server for processing but cannot find a way to have them listed in a listbox without specifying the full file name

i.e. `TB2014-09-08_11h48m25_765.txt` is a full name. `TB` stays constant and the files are always `.txt`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want the [GetFiles method in the Directory class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) (System.IO namespace). Something along these lines:

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("c:\YourFolder", "TB*.txt")

For Each filename In files
   Console.WriteLine(filename)
Next
```

Comment: it works well for local addresses but not for the URL address:"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: URI formats are not supported."

Comment: You can't access a directory listing over http. You would have to use the physical network path. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964983/get-file-names-and-directory-list-from-web-directory

Comment: is mapPath available to use in VB?

Comment: Yes but that will only get you the path on the server, which is not necesarilly the same as the path from the client.

Comment: how do I implement it from a VB winform? Sorry I am still new to this whole process and I'm learning on the go. I know the direct URL path but won't know what the full file names are due to the custom date stamps. and yes the date stamps are very important to maintain (used on first-come-first-serve basis)

Comment: Server.MapPath is a method used in and ASP.NET project (your question is tagged asp.net) so why are you now asking about WinForms?