# ASP.NET Get all pages of website

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, url, sitemap

I want to parse some websites and get list of all pages on current domain, like a:

> sample.com/
>
> sample.com/page1/
>
> sample.com/page2.html

But I can't find samples, how to build this sitemap or tree using C# and ASP.NET

I found only one example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13486/A-Simple-Crawler-Using-C-Sockets

But I can't understand, how author use it

`if(Directory.Exists(strUri) == true)
    {
        //some code
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
        FileInfo[] fia = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
    }`

When I use this code, result in `if` is always `false`. When I use only

`GetFiles` function

I have Exception:

> URI formats are not supported

Who have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

remember that on a Web ambient, you cant read files that way, you need to use

`Server.MapPath(url)`

to get the physical address to the files, then you can do the loop you are using.

Comment: This is not my sites. Are you sure that `MapPath` can work with url?

Comment: you can't do that, a virtual address is not a "folder", and a simple http doesn't have it, However. There ARE many extensions to the HTTP protocol. WebDAV IS a protocol for mapping an HTTP URI to a directory in some location. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399358/webdav-request-show-files-in-folder for how to query a WebDAV service for the content of a fold